# removeConnection results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios9, coremidi

This is Apple's code

```
- (BOOL)removeConnection: (MIDINetworkConnection *)connection;
```

in

```
-[MIDINetworkSession removeConnection:]
```

yet it results in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This only happens in iOS 9.

Any help or workarounds?

Comment: Similar issue with a few more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957397/midinetworkconnection-bad-access-on-dealloc-ios-9?noredirect=1#comment53750161_32957397

Comment: FYI this crash also happens if you have any reference to MIDINetworkSession.defaultSession in your code, connect to your iOS device using WiFi MIDI via a Mac's 'Audio / MIDI Setup', and then press disconnect again.

Comment: Thanks, @ephemer I'm pretty sure I have all of those cases covered in my code, but I'll double check.

Comment: @Yar, yes, for me just storing the connections that once existed in, as you put it, `connectionsThatHaveBeenClosed`, was enough

Comment: Now I call it `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *arcBugsInIos9RetainTheseConnections;` ;)

Comment: I haven't measured it but I cannot imagine that this leak is significant. I'd put it on the who-cares list, and someday we can remove this awful code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yar's answer helped me, except it doesn't cover the case where a disconnection happens from the other device. Instead of storing the objects to an array in removeConnection: I have a manager object that listens to the MIDINetworkNotificationSessionDidChange notification, looks for any new connections, and adds the references to an NSMutableSet.

So, in my manager init I have:

```
self.connRefs = [NSMutableSet set];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(sessionChanged:) 
     name:MIDINetworkNotificationSessionDidChange object:nil];
[self sessionChanged:nil];
```

... and my sessionChanged: method:

```
- (void)sessionChanged:(NSNotification *)n {
  // ios9 bug hack to keep ref to prevent bad_exec
  for (MIDINetworkConnection *c in [MIDINetworkSession defaultSession].connections) {
    [self.connRefs addObject:c];
  }
}
```

That seems like a fast way to figure out how to store a reference to each connection, no matter who initiated it. Then when the connection is removed (either by your app, or the other device), the reference is already stored, and no crash!

Comment: Great point and advance on this question. Can you explain why I should use an `NSMutableDictionary` instead of just throwing them in an `NSMutableSet`? Are you going to use those keys again to remove the thing?

Comment: No, that's a great point as well. A set would be a better choice.

Comment: Edited to use @Yar's suggestion of a set.

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as the accepted answer though I have yet to test it out myself. I *have* confirmed that my answer does not hit the case of a MIDI connection initiated from *and* removed from the computer (which is basically a missing use-case in my testing).

Comment: This is in MIDI Designer latest, BTW. Also: this is fixed in 9.2. Of course, unless you want to target 9.2, this is very WTF ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's the `MIDINetworkConnection` that's getting `dealloced` and causing the issue.

The workaround that I'm using is that I add these objects to an `NSMutableArray` before calling `removeConnection:` (mine is called `connectionsThatHaveBeenClosed` ;) ). Unfortunately, I have to keep this array growing until the App is closed, which is a leak.

Comment: Yeah this is what I feared I'd have to do. Has anyone created a bug report?

Comment: Hi @HariKaramSingh! Not that I know of. If you manage to find anything or submit anything, I'd love to know about it. Thank you!

Comment: I submitted a bug report referencing this and my SO post. And I'm about to use one of my dev support tickets for connectivity issues with iOS9. Will let you know...

Comment: @HariKaramSingh if it's a radar, there's a URL? Maybe not... thank you for doing that!

Comment: Filed with apple but I just made an OpenRadar version: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6168166984056832  Is there an automatic way to keep these in sync?

Comment: I'm unaware of any way to keep them synced. Thanks for filing the Radar and sharing... my GUESS is that this all gets fixed without any reference to either your bug report nor your Radar, but we shall see. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, my hopes and prayers are on 9.1. I'd fine-tuned the bonjour net scan and connectivity and now it's a holics! For your interest: https://github.com/Air-Craft/MIDIFish

Comment: interesting! Have you seen MidiBus, too?