# MIDINetworkConnection BAD_ACCESS on dealloc (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, ios9, bonjour, coremidi

I've got a strange Network MIDI issue that's arisen in iOS 9 which
effectively works like the following:

1. I do a NSNetServiceBrowser scan for wifi midi devices.
2. It finds my macbook and I create a MIDINetworkConnection with the host
   from the NSNetService and store this in an ivar
3. I do another scan some time later which nils the ivar. This causes a
   BAD_ACCESS in the internal dealloc of MIDINetworkConnection

Stack trace:

```
#0 0x000000019902dbd0 in objc_msgSend ()
#1 0x0000000184c41698 in _MIDINetworkHostImpl::~_MIDINetworkHostImpl() ()
#2 0x0000000184c40a50 in -[MIDINetworkConnection dealloc] ()
#3 0x0000000199035ae8 in (anonymous
namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#4 0x000000018430cb6c in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#5 0x0000000189c34d48 in _prepareForCAFlush ()
#6 0x0000000189c3a1e8 in _beforeCACommitHandler ()
```

Any ideas or pointers to dig deeper?

Comment: It looks like the midi object is holding An unretained reference to an object that you are releasing. Make sure that the midi framework isn't using that object before you release ir

Comment: Same issue as this? [removeConnection results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686214/removeconnection-results-in-exc-bad-access)

Comment: Yeah it is similar, thank you.  With regards to it being a unretained ref - I'm not so sure. If the ref to the ObjC object were deallocated beforehand then it wouldn't produce bad_access by setting the ivar to nil. The fact that it invokes the dealloc implies the object is alive when the ivar is nil'ed. The bad_access instead looks like something that's happening in inside the deconstructor of the underlying C++ object.

Comment: I think the tag bonjour is not relevant? Also, I think this is exactly the same as the other question, but +1 anyway